# Remove flags from LDFLAGS, CPPFLAGS using Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

At one point, I did the following on the terminal (Mac Big Sur 11.1):

```
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/include"
```

Since then, I have uninstalled the app and I would love to get rid of those flags... But, I don't know how to even start. How do I remove those flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've added them to something like `.profile` or `.bashrc`, etc... that gets read on login, they're likely not set any longer. Just exporting them will not cause them to persist past restarts.

To see if they're still set, do `echo ${LDFLAGS}` and see if there's a value.

If so, check your home directory for files like those mentioned above or possibly `.zprofile` or `.zshrc` since you're on macOS 11. Look in those files to see if the environment variables are being set there and remove them.

To get rid of them for your current session, just unset them.

```
unset LDFLAGS
unset CPPFLAGS
```